# Call to a member function move() on string

Tags: php, laravel, file, file-upload, image-uploading

Kindly assist me with the code below. I keep getting this error "Call to a member function move() on string" when am trying to upload multiple images.Thanks in advance.

This is the code for my view page

```
  {!!Form::open(['method'=>'POST','action'=>'ClientController@uploadLand','files'=>true])!!}
         {{ csrf_field() }}

          <div class="admin-form">

            <div class="row">
              <div id="maindiv">
                  <div id="formdiv">
                      <div id="filediv"><input name="file[]" type="file" id="file"/></div><br/>
                      <input type="button" id="add_more" class="upload" value="Add More Files"/>
                     <!--  <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit" id="upload" class="upload"/> -->
                      <br/>
                      <br/>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>
  {!!Form::close()!!}
```

This the controller code

```
public function uploadLand(Request $request)
{
    for($i=0;$i<count($_FILES["file"]["name"]);$i++){

    $image= "";
    $file_path="images/uploads";
    $imageName = $_FILES['file']['name'][$i];
    $image->move(public_path($file_path),$imageName);
    //$image->move_uploaded_file("images/uploads".$imageName);

    }
 }
```

Comment: You are calling the method `move` on the string that you defined here: `$image = "";`

Comment: How do I go about it...kindly advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code :

```
if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
    $destinationPath = 'path/th/save/file/';
    $files = $request->file('file'); // will get all files

    foreach ($files as $file) {//this statement will loop through all files.
        $file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName(); //Get file original name
        $file->move($destinationPath , $file_name); // move files to destination folder
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain why this is correct, rather than just giving code example

Comment: I get this error message when I implement your code Pankaj "Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on string"

Comment: That was awesome mate,It worked...thanks for the assist